# Fixing an Apache Inifinte Loop - Determine referer

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have the following Apache configs setup:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms
RewriteRule .* /cmssystem46/wp-content/uploads/test_script.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my `/cmssystem46/wp-content/uploads/test_script.php` file I have setup the following code:

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet - load the bare-bones of WordPress*/
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../wp-blog-header.php');



if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    auth_redirect(); // THIS PART WORKS ALREADY
}else{
    $a = explode ('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    array_shift($a);
    array_shift($a);
    $c = implode('/', $a);
    header('Location: '.get_site_url().'/'.$c.'');
    exit();
}
```

Do you see the problem? There is an infinite loop between a resource located in wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/* and the test_script.php file.

I need to fix this. Conceptually this sounds really easy: I add a new Apache rule like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /cmssystem46/wp-content/uploads/test_script.php
RewriteRule .* - [L] # i.e. don't do anything if the php script is redirecting back to this resource.
```

...However this doesn't work. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

## Brief Background

I'm tasked with securing the wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms folder so that only WordPress-authenticated users have access to its files/media.

The Apache .htaccess rewriterules (above) says "any HTTP requests to the wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms directory should be directed to the wp-content/uploads/test_script.php file for processing."

Once a user comes to the test_scirpt.php file, they are checked to see if they are logged into WP, if not, they are directed to the WordPress login screen. All of this works.

IF they are ARE authenticated in WordPress they are redirected back to their original wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/* file they were trying to request.

This is an explanation of the code I have pasted above.

What is happening is now is that the PHP file and the Apache htaccess file are playing marry-go-round with each other; I need to tell Apache "STOP the redirection process if the referer that just made the call to wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/* is test_script.php" ... does this make more sense?

Comment: So what does your `get_site_url() . $c` generate? probably you've got php redirecting P->Q, and then your htaccess bounces it right back with `Q->P`

Comment: Hey Marc - get_site_url().$c is literally the url that the user was trying to access initially. So on my localhost machine the literal url will be: `http://localhost/cmssystem46/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/<resource-name>`

Comment: I should be clear: on the user's browser's address bar the URL never changes during these redirects. These are all internal redirects.

Comment: so there you go. since your rewrites have no anchors, you match the specified string ANYWHERE in the url, which rewrites to your .php url. then that php url redirects BACK to your gravity_forms url, which then gets redirected by mod_rewrite again, blah blah blah.

Comment: No. Only your rewriterule is internal. PHP is doing a full-blown client-side redirect.

Comment: Hey @Marc B, thanks, so what do you suggest? I am not an Apache expert, so your holding my hand through this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @MustafaG What are you trying to achieve with this RewriteRule/PHP redirect combination?

Comment: @MustafaG And what is the difference between `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `get_site_url().'/'.$c`?

Comment: Thanks Olaf! I have added a 'Brief Background' section, please see if this makes my issue more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't redirect the client to its original request. I'd rather just serve the file from the script itself, e.g. (taken in part from http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#example-2687)

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    auth_redirect(); // THIS PART WORKS ALREADY
} else {
    $basedir = '/path/to/wp-content/uploads/gravity-forms/';
    $file = realpath($basedir . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if ($file === false || strpos($file, $basedir) !== 0 || !file_exists($file)) {
        // error
    } else {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

This way, you avoid the redirect loop, one roundtrip to the client, and also serve the file faster.

Comment: Hey Olaf, thanks - I should have updated here that I had come to a solution, very similar to what you have proposed. This answer of yours should be helpful for anyone else who may encounter a similar problem as me.